# Change Audience in a given Post with the Facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

is it possible to change the Audience of an already existing Post in my Timeline with the iOS Facebook SDK? If so, can someone give me a hint on how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API for this - you could delete and re-create the post with new privacy settings if the original post was made by your app, but otherwise this needs to be done from Facebook's native interface